# Separate Cover page for dita-topic's title

Tags: dita

I'm creating a `dita` topic file (`xyz.dita`) having some other `dita` topics nested in it but I need to create a separate cover page using the main title of the topic..

I need to generate a separate cover-page with the title only..

It's basic structure is like this:

```
<topic id="topic_id">
    <title>Title to be in Cover Page</title>

    <topic>
         <title>normal title</title>
    .
    .
    </topic>

    <topic>
    .
    .
    </topic>

</topic>
```

Comment: You haven’t stated a question or specified what you need help with. Could you describe the problem you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the solution by playing around some other script files in the plugin..

So, here it is...

```
<xsl:template match="topic[@id = 'topic_id']">
  <fo:page-sequence master-reference="front-matter-first">
    <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="title"/>
    </fo:block>
  </fo:flow>
 </fo:page-sequence>

 <fo:page-sequence master-reference="body-odd">
    <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
       <xsl:apply-templates select="//topic/topic"/>
     </fo:flow>
  </fo:page-sequence>
</xsl:template>
```